# Change swagger host and port serving it statically

Tags: json, rest, swagger

Inspired by [this sample repository,](https://github.com/johanbrandhorst/grpc-gateway-boilerplate) I'm generating a swagger output in json with `protoc` and serving it. However, for certain reasons I'm hosting the swagger content on a different port(`:10000`) than my REST api service(`:8000`).

I'm using the Go library `statik` to bundle up the swagger assets and serve them. It works, and a webpage is served when going to `localhost:10000`.

However, every `cURL` request swagger makes seems to be confined to just that - `localhost:10000`. The REST API lives on `localhost:8081`.

Serving swagger-ui with static content, how do I change the host/port for the REST api server?

I've tried going into the `index.html` of the swagger-ui content to add `basePath` as here, but with no luck. Every request is still made to `:10000`

```
    window.onload = function() {
      // Begin Swagger UI call region
      const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: "./service.swagger.json",
        dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
        deepLinking: true,
        presets: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
          SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
        ],
        plugins: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
        ],
        layout: "StandaloneLayout",
        // I added this, but it did not change anything.
        basePath: "localhost:8081"
      })
      // End Swagger UI call region
      window.ui = ui}
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `host` with value `localhost:8081`
2. Remove `basePath`, basePath is used to change the relative path after host i.e if your web server is hosted at `/v1/` etc, then you can use basepath to change that

i am still trying to find out how to pass host value dynamically for production, stage, dev env